# Unable to run update statement using Dapper (parameters error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-update, dapper, micro-orm

I am trying to update a row using Dapper but I am having error on specifying parameters in my update statement

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Not enough parameters specified.  The command
requires 3 parameter(s), but only 0 parameter(s) exist in the
parameter collection.
```

Repository.cs

```
public void Update(Movie movie)
{
      var sql = "UPDATE myDB.movies set title=?, genre=? where Id=?";
      db.Execute(sql, new 
               {   movie.Title, 
                   movie.Genre, 
                   movie.ID 
               });
}
```

Movie.cs

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Release Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I am using `iDB2Connection` to access an IBM ISeries Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Workaround 1**

What I did was to name parameters such that their order stays the same regardless of Dapper's alphabetical ordering.

```
public void Update(Movie movie)
{
  var sql = "UPDATE myDB.movies set title=@param1, genre=@param2 where ID=@param3";
  db.Execute(sql, new { param1 = movie.Title, param2 = movie.Genre, param3 = movie.ID });
}
```

If someone knows a better solution. please post in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this in your `Repository.cs` file

```
public void Update(Movie movie)
{
      var sql = "UPDATE myDB.movies set title=:Title, genre=:Genre where Id=:ID";
      db.Execute(sql, new 
               {  
                  Title = movie.Title, 
                  Genre = movie.Genre, 
                  ID = movie.ID 
               });
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. I think it is somehow rearranging the parameters

Comment: please check your passing correct data to your fields. Which means, you cant assign a string value to integer field..

Comment: I have debugged & data seems to be fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46208/discussion-between-damien-joe-and-biby-augustine)

Comment: it's worth pointing out that if the param name is the same as the property name, then no key is needed. in the example about - ```new {movie.Title, movie.Genre, movie.ID}``` will be enough