# Should Dapper be able to access a private getter?

Tags: c#, orm, db2, dapper

I'm working with Dapper and DB2.  As far as I can see DB2 doesn't support GUID's natively, so I'm storing it as a string and using dappers access to private properties to help out.

```cs
class TestTable
{
    public string RequestId
    {
        get { return RequestGuid.ToString(); }
        private set { RequestGuid = new Guid(value); }
    }

    public Guid RequestGuid { get; set; }
}
```

I would rather RequestId was fully private, however if I do that the following fails

```cs
    connection.Execute("INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (REQUESTID) VALUES(@REQUESTID)"
        , new TestTable() { RequestGuid = Guid.NewGuid() });
```

The error is

> Not enough parameters specified.  The command requires 1 parameter(s), but only 0 parameter(s) exist in the parameter collection.

Should dapper be able to access a private getter?

**Edit:**

The `connection.Execute` works if I use the class as it is shown.  I get the error if I make the RequestId private.

Comment: `RequestGuid` is not `@REQUESTID`

Comment: @StuartLC unless I'm missing something, I've passed a TestTable class to dapper, which includes a RequestId param which maps to the `@REQUESTID` in the SQL.

Comment: You are right - I didn't trace through your class correctly. Out of interest, can you try map directly using an anonymous class (with matching property names), just to see if it is perhaps an issue such as Case Sensitivity, i.e. 
`connection.Execute("INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (REQUESTID) VALUES(@REQUESTID)"
        , new { REQUESTID = Guid.NewGuid() });`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it worked (I had to add `.ToString()`).  I also tried changing the parameter name in the TestTable class to uppercase REQUESTID, but the problem persists.

Comment: It could be that the client used by Dapper for DB2 doesn't support named parameters - you might have the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21424388/314291) (assuming multiple params)